# i missed maghrib what now?

Tags: salat

I unintentionally missed maghrib as I am secretly following Islam and I can not do it due to my family and extensive work so I joined isha with maghrib have I done a sin please reply I am crying!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalmu Alaikum Warahmatullahi Warbarakatuh,

Firstly a very warm welcome to Islam, May Allah Ta'ala continue to help and strenghten you all the way to jannatul fidous. And guide the rest of your family with His endless nur (light) too, Ameen x

Maybe this is a very late reply, but i just came across this website today.
 So here goes, It comes in the Hadith in Sahih Al Bukhari Shareef: On the authority of Anas (RA)that Our Beloved Prophet Muhammed (SAW) said:" If anyone forgets their Salah, then he should pray it when he remembers, there is no expiation, except to pray the same."

So in your case you would just read your 3 Fardh of Maghrib of Qadha (meaning the missed Salah). and You can pray this this 3 Fardh of Maghrib Salah that you have missed before or after your Isha Salah.

Remember even when you sin, always ask Allah The Most High, for forgiveness, He is always with us and the Most forgiving, Never lose hope in Allah. Our beloved prophet (SAW) says "The one who repents from his sins is the like the one who has no sin"

May Safeguard all our imaans and Forgive us all, Ameen

And Allah knows best

Comment: I asked forgiveness that I will try my best not to do it again but can not promise to Allah that i will not do it again as it is hard to pray in my family presence thank you may Allah forgive me

Comment: Ameen May Allah forgive us all. Don't worry be strong, Allah the Most High knows you are trying, He will make it easy for you. Remember all this patience and struggle you are going through, none will go to waste. Allah The Most Merciful says: in chapter 11 (surah hud: verse 115) "And be patient, for surely Allah does not waste the reward of the good-doers."

Answer (score 0):

Asalam Alikum,

Combining Zuhr+Asr or Maghrib+Isha is allowed under certain circumstances, not sure if your case is one of them. 
Here is a link describing the issue (http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/85574/combining-two-prayers)

I ask Allah to help you and to give you the strength to continue practicing Islam.

Comment: I had prayed maghrib 3 rakkat separately in isha time ( I was unaware ) that they need to be combined how can I combine them? And dobi need to pray again or nie just pray isha as I prayed maggrib already in isha time

Comment: @abd you've done it correctly. combining doesn't mean praying 7 raka'as at once but praying them one after an other.